# Configure html-loader to replace ng-src attributes

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-html-loader

How do I configure html-loader to replace my ng-src attributes with the correct path?  I have a legacy application that has something like -

```
<img ng-src="{{path}}/test.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at example section of docs ( https://github.com/webpack/html-loader ) :

```
&attrs[]=img:ng-src
```